# Close the app when back is pressed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

i want shut the app when user clicks on back button. My flow is like this

First Time Log in:

Log in Screen A-> Main Page B
Now i want to close the app when user press the back button.It is coming back to log in screen. What should i do?

Answer (score 3):

whils starting the `Main page` from `Login` activity, finish the `login` page . so in the activity stack there will be no login page. So From the Main page when you press the back button it will close the app.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it :) Just call `finish();` after you call a `startActivity(i);`

Answer (score 3):

When you start activity B from A using intent then put `finish()` after starting the activity. This will kill the current activity that is your login page from stack and when user presses back, he will exit the application.
Sample code is :

```
Intent intent = new Intent((getApplicationContext(),B.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 2):

For each and every **Intent** you have used for going into other activity u have to follow this way for passing intent just pass **flag** to each intent as given below and after starting **Activity** using **startActivity()** u have to add **finish()** after that demo code as given below

```
Intent i=new Intent(firstActivity.this,secondActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the similar Discussion of your Problem. .[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109529/android-close-app-on-back-button)

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    onBackPressed();

}

return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }

 public void onBackPressed() {
Intent myIntent = new Intent(B.this, A.class);
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);//clear the backstack
startActivity(myIntent);
finish();
return;
   }
```

Above Code is Explained [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829918/how-to-close-my-android-app-when-i-click-the-back-button-from-my-mobile)
Just Clear The Activity Stack and then finish the Activity.. Thats it your App will be closed then .

Answer (score 1):

In your second activity that is 'B' you should override the `onBackPressed` method to finish from the current application. So you can do it as shown below:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Exiting application...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      this.finish();
}
```

This thing had helped me. I hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 1):

you can finish activity but you can't exit from application because android design is not for exit application by choice. Rather you can call home intent to bring home infront :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

One More Way is here:

Try this, Add noHistory in you mainifest file each and every activity.

#### `android:noHistory="true"`

Answer (score 0):

OverRide method

```
onBackPressed(){
//desired task like
//finish Activity here
}
```

and finish activity there